# Comparing strings extracted from Jobname

Tags: conditionals, strings, xstring

I have some code that parses `\jobname`, but it's not working as expected. I've included a minimal example below where the file name is `HelloWorld.tex`. When I print the `\jobname`, it comes out as "HelloWorld". When I compare it with the string "HelloWorld" using, for example, `xstring`'s `\IfStrEq`, they are not equal. Why?

I'm running on OSX using the MacTeX version of TeX Live.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}
\noindent
.HelloWorld.\\
.\jobname.\\
\IfStrEq{\jobname}{HelloWorld}{Yes}{No}\\

\end{document}
```

The output when this is compiled is

> .HelloWorld.
>
> .HelloWorld.
>
> No

Comment: In Windows 8.1 64bit my output is:
`.HelloWorld.
.texstudio_gS2832.
No`

Comment: @GiacomoAlessandroni, to compare, you need to replace `HelloWorld` by the same file name you are compiling.

Comment: @Sigur, Ok I have see now: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Temp\texstudio_gS2832.pdf"`

Comment: @Sigur Now I have the same result and... unfortunately I have not an answer.

Answer (score 12):

The `\jobname` primitive is a TeX string, so all characters have category code 12 (other) not 11 (letter) (with the exception of any spaces, which are category code 10 (space)). Slightly confusingly, `xstring` is carrying out a token-based comparison here not a string one! Assuming e-TeX is available you can fix your code easily

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}
\noindent
.HelloWorld.\\
.\jobname.\\
\IfStrEq{\jobname}{\detokenize{HelloWorld}}{Yes}{No}\\

\end{document}
```

There are alternatives available. For example, with any recent TeX engine other than Knuth's TeX you can do a string comparison directly

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

\begin{document}
\noindent
.test.\\
.\jobname.\\
\makeatletter
\ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\jobname}{HelloWorld}=0 Yes\else No\fi
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Sticking to classical TeX, it is possible to set up a comparison by using `\meaning` to detokenize the content of a macro. That's available in LaTeX as `\@onelevel@sanitize`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\noindent
.test.\\
.\jobname.\\
\makeatletter
\edef\@tempa{\jobname}
\def\@tempb{HelloWorld}
\@onelevel@sanitize\@tempb
\ifx\@tempa\@tempb Yes\else No\fi
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Addlai I don't tend to use `xstring` so missed that one:  a self-answer would be good. The fact that `\jobname` is a string is consistent with other parts of TeX and is quite straight-forward I'd say :-)

Answer (score 8):

I just realized there is another easy solution. The `xstring` package has starred versions of its comparison commands that do not take category codes into account. All that is necessary to make the file work is to replace `\IfStrEq` by `\IfStrEq*`.

Comment: Thanks so much. I was reading answer after answer without getting anywhere, and this does the trick.