# Codeblock execution conditional on filename

Tags: conditionals

When making minutes of a meeting, I use two .tex files: an agenda- and a minutes file. The first one is included in the second one with the pdfpages package.

Now, whilst the two files are identical in structure, the minutes file has additional content.

However, when I make a change in the structure of each file, this should be changed in both files, for consistency.

What I'm looking for is a way to work with one file, in which the "structure"- and "content" LaTeX code blocks can be made to be executed dependend on the filename; this way, my workflow is more efficient. (I'll just keep two copies of the same file)

**Minimal Working Example**

agenda.tex

```
\documentclass[agenda]{meetingmins}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item{Agendapoint 1} % Always to be executed -- core structure

Content of agendapoint one 
%to be executed conditional on filename minutes.tex
More content of agendapoint one 


\item{Agendapoint 2}

...


\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

minutes.tex

```
\documentclass{meetingmins}

\usepackage{pdfpages}   

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=-]{agenda} % Conditional on filename minutes.tex

\begin{enumerate}

\item{Agendapoint 1} % Always to be executed -- core structure

Content of agendapoint one 
%to be executed conditional on filename minutes.tex
More content of agendapoint one 


\item{Agendapoint 2}

...


\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: And by looking into a magic chrystal ball I found that you should give us more information

Comment: A very interesting question.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243591/comparing-strings-extracted-from-jobname

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Did I give enough information? If not, I'd be more than happy to add to it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a suggestion based on the following assumptions:

1. You want to enumerate agenda items; and
2. Conditionally print a summary of the enumerated agenda items.

We address (1) by writing agenda items as `\section`s. You already do this using `\item{...}` (which doesn't take a mandatory argument anyway), hence my suggestion. (2) would be equivalent to writing a `\tableofcontents`, which summarizes the listed agenda items.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\printagenda}{\tableofcontents}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Agenda}

\newcommand{\agendaitem}[1]{\section{#1}}

\begin{document}

\printagenda

\agendaitem{Agenda point one}

Content related to agenda item one.
More content related to agenda item one.

\agendaitem{Agenda point two}

Content related to agenda item two.
More content related to agenda item two.

\end{document}
```

Using the above as a starting point, you can format the **Agenda** using a package like [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) and the sectional layout using (say) [`sectsty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) (or otherwise).

I've introduced context-related syntax that replicates your intent. It makes for a clearer understanding of the code, even though the macros are fairly simple.